# how to copy a field from a document-set to a field in the document inside

Tags: document-library, document, document-set

I have a document set with a field called DocumentSetAuthors (it is a person or group column).

Inside this document-set user can add a document type called Document1. Document1 has a DocumentAuthors column(it  is also a person or group column).

How can I copy the the DocumentSetAuthors to DocumentAuthors column automatically (perhaps with a workflow)

Answer (score 0):

With Document Sets, there are Shared Columns that have been baked into the content type.  When you share a column, every document within the Document Set will have that metadata if you share that column.

To set up shared columns on your document library, you have to:

1. Click Library Settings.
2. Click on Document Set content type link
   *If all the content types are not shown, you have to Allow
   Management of content types in Advanced Settings*.
3. Click Document Set settings and add the columns you want to be shared in the Shared Columns Section.

[image: Document Set Settings]
[image: Shared Column Settings]